# Passing Array from AJAX to PHP, then passing data back as JSON

Tags: php, json

I am having a strange issue with my PHP / JSON data being returned by PHP.  Here is my PHP:

```
            <?php
            /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
            * Easy set variables
            */

            /* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
            * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
            */

            // add your columns here!!!
                $aColumns = array( 'Action', 'TimeOccurred', 'UserName', 'IPv4From', 'ShareName', 'FullFilePath', 'NewPathName', 'FromServer' );
                //$aColumns = $_POST['selcolumns'];
                //$aColumns = explode("-", $aColumns);

                foreach ($aColumns as $col) {
                    file_put_contents( '../php/php-debug.txt', $col." ", FILE_APPEND );
                }

                $server = "";
                $database = array("Database" => "");
                $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $database); 
                if ($conn === false) die("<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));



            /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
                $sIndexColumn = "GUID";

            /* DB table to use */
                $sTable = $_POST['table'];

            /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
            * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
            * no need to edit below this line
            */

            /*
            * Local functions
            */
                function fatal_error ( $sErrorMessage = '' ) {
                    header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' 500 Internal Server Error' );
                    die( $sErrorMessage );
                }

            /* Ordering */
                $sOrder = "";
                if ( isset( $_POST['order'] ) ) {
                    $sOrder = "ORDER BY ";
                    if ( $_POST['columns'][0]['orderable'] == "true" ) {
                        $sOrder .= "".$aColumns[ intval( $_POST['order'][0]['column'] ) ]." ".
                        ($_POST['order'][0]['dir']==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc');
                    }
                }

            /* escape function */
                function mssql_escape($data) {
                    if(is_numeric($data))
                    return $data;
                    $unpacked = unpack('H*hex', $data);
                    return '0x' . $unpacked['hex'];
                }

            /* Filtering */
                $sWhere = "";
                if ( isset($_POST['search']['value']) && $_POST['search']['value'] != "" ) {
                    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
                    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ ) {
                        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".addslashes( $_POST['search']['value'] )."%' OR ";
                    }
                    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
                    $sWhere .= ')';
                }

            /* Individual column filtering */
                for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ ) {
                    if ( isset($_POST['columns'][$i]) && $_POST['columns'][$i]['searchable'] == "true" && $_POST['columns'][$i]['search']['value'] != '' ) {
                        if ( $sWhere == "" ) {
                            $sWhere = "WHERE ";
                        }
                        else {
                            $sWhere .= " AND ";
                        }
                        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".addslashes($_POST['columns'][$i]['search']['value'])."%' ";
                    }
                }

            /* Add the custom Date/Time filter */

                if ( $sWhere == "" ) {
                    $sWhere = "WHERE (TimeOccurred >= "."'".$_POST['datestart']."'"." AND TimeOccurred <= "."'".$_POST['dateend']."')";
                }
                else {
                    $sWhere .= " AND (TimeOccurred >= "."'".$_POST['datestart']."'"." AND TimeOccurred <= "."'".$_POST['dateend']."')";
                }

            /* Paging */
                $top = (isset($_POST['start']))?((int)$_POST['start']):0 ;   
                $limit = (isset($_POST['length']))?((int)$_POST['length'] ):5;
                $sQuery = "SELECT TOP $limit ".implode(', ', $aColumns)." FROM $sTable $sWhere ".(($sWhere=="")?" WHERE ":" AND ")." $sIndexColumn NOT IN ( SELECT TOP $top $sIndexColumn FROM $sTable $sOrder ) $sOrder";
                $rResult = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sQuery);
                if($rResult === false){
                    die(sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ERRORS));
                }

            /* Data set length after filtering */
                $sQueryCnt = "SELECT * FROM $sTable $sWhere";
                $rResultCnt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sQueryCnt, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
                $iFilteredTotal = sqlsrv_num_rows( $rResultCnt );

            /* Total data set length */
                $sQuery = "SELECT COUNT(GUID) FROM $sTable";
                $rResultTotal = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sQuery, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
                $aResultTotal = sqlsrv_fetch_array($rResultTotal, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);
                $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];

            /* Output */
                $output = array(
                    "draw" => intval($_POST['draw']),
                    "recordsTotal" => $iTotal,
                    "recordsFiltered" => $iFilteredTotal,
                    "data" => array()
                );

                while ( $aRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $rResult, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                    $row = array();
                    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ ) {
                        $row[$aColumns[$i]] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
                    }
                    $output['data'][] = $row;
                }

                echo json_encode( $output );

            ?>
```

The part of the code that has me stuck:

```
            $aColumns = array( 'Action', 'TimeOccurred', 'UserName', 'IPv4From', 'ShareName', 'FullFilePath', 'NewPathName', 'FromServer' );
            //$aColumns = $_POST['selcolumns'];
            //$aColumns = explode("-", $aColumns);

            foreach ($aColumns as $col) {
                file_put_contents( '../php/php-debug.txt', $col." ", FILE_APPEND );
            }
```

If I leave my code as is and run through the process I get the data back as expected and everything works.  I also get this output in my php-debug.txt:

Action TimeOccurred UserName IPv4From ShareName FullFilePath NewPathName FromServer

If I modify these lines of my code to this:

```
            //$aColumns = array( 'Action', 'TimeOccurred', 'UserName', 'IPv4From', 'ShareName', 'FullFilePath', 'NewPathName', 'FromServer' );
            $aColumns = $_POST['selcolumns'];
            $aColumns = explode("-", $aColumns);

            foreach ($aColumns as $col) {
                file_put_contents( '../php/php-debug.txt', $col." ", FILE_APPEND );
            }
```

I do not get the data back as expected.  I get a warning stating invalid JSON response and in my php-debug.txt I get this content:

Action TimeOccurred UserName IPv4From ShareName FullFilePath NewPathName FromServer

It is driving me bonkers that the array has the same values either way and yet it doesn't work.  There is an extra space on the end of the php-debug.txt the 2nd time around, not sure where that comes from or if it is the problem.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Try `var_dump($aColumns);` before your foreach to see if the data looks like you think it should

Comment: This is what I see: array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }   , unfortunately there is no way I'm aware of to open that php file in a browser and pass it POST data to fill the array.

Comment: It's looking in `$_POST` for the variables. If it's not coming from a form, you're going to figure out where its supposed to be coming from.

Comment: It is coming from a form into AJAX which is being passed to this server-side PHP script.  Then at the end it is passed back as JSON data.  Since the AJAX/Form are on different php files than the server side script, I can't open that server-side script in a browser and have the $_POST variables available.  That being said, the contents of $aColumns are being written to php-debug.txt during the process and it shows the same values both ways.

Comment: Is there a chance that `$_POST['selcolumns']` is not set and there's a `PHP Notice:  Undefined index` in the output coming back? Why not try suppressing any warnings `$aColumns = @$_POST['selcolumns'];`

Comment: If that was the case there would be nothing written to php-debug.txt right?

Comment: `$col` would be empty, but you are adding a `" "` before appending to the file, so that is likely where the extra space you mentioned was coming from

Comment: i think that is where the space is coming from.  $col is not empty though as the values I'm expecting are being printed to php-debug.txt and they are the same values no matter how I fill the array, yet I get a different result.

Comment: I think I got this partially figured out my implode in the SQL statement is coming out as: Action, TimeOccurred, UserName, IPv4From, ShareName, FullFilePath, NewPathName, FromServer,   instead I need Action, TimeOccurred, UserName, IPv4From, ShareName, FullFilePath, NewPathName, FromServer.  So I need to figure out how to remove the trailing comma/space.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  For some reason there is an extra element being added to my array, but its an empty element so when I print there is nothing there.  I added this to my code array_pop($aColumns); and for now that resolved the problem.  Its kind of a dirty workout though, and I can't help but think that eventually there will come a scenario where the last element isn't blank and its something I need.  Would love to figure out a cleaner solution.